# How to change font face

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

So what I'm trying to do is add new type of font to my website, but the problem, I'm getting stuck, I need to add from Open Sans 4 types of text:

bold, regular, bolditalic, italic

Previously I already added other fonts but, It was always one from different families. This is my code:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Josefin'; src: url("font/Josefin.ttf"); }
@font-face { font-family: 'Roboto'; src: url("font/Roboto.ttf"); }
/*
@font-face { font-family: 'OpenSans'; src: url("font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"); }
@font-face { font-family: 'OpenSans'; src: url("font/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"); }
@font-face { font-family: 'OpenSans'; src: url("font/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf"); }
@font-face { font-family: 'OpenSans'; src: url("font/OpenSans-Italic.ttf"); }   
*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, .bold{ font-family: 'Josefin'; }
p, li, ul, ol, a, .light{ font-family: 'Roboto'; }
```

the h tags I was trying to change them to the "OpenSans-Italic" but I don't know how to call the specific font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@font-face { 
font-family: 'OpenSans'; 
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url('OpenSans-Regular.eot#')  format('eot'),
              url('OpenSans-Regular.woff')  format('woff'),
              url('OpenSans-Regular.ttf')   format('truetype'),
              url('OpenSans-Regular.svg#svgOpenSans')  format('svg'); 
}

@font-face { 
font-family: 'OpenSans'; 
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
src: url('OpenSans-Bold.eot#')  format('eot'),
              url('OpenSans-Bold.woff')  format('woff'),
              url('OpenSans-Bold.ttf')   format('truetype'),
              url('OpenSans-Bold.svg#svgOpenSans')  format('svg'); 
}

@font-face { 
font-family: 'OpenSans'; 
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
src: url('OpenSans-BoldItalic.eot#')  format('eot'),
              url('OpenSans-BoldItalic.woff')  format('woff'),
              url('OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf')   format('truetype'),
              url('OpenSans-BoldItalic.svg#svgOpenSans')  format('svg'); 
}

@font-face { 
font-family: 'OpenSans'; 
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
src: url('OpenSans-Italic.eot#')  format('eot'),
              url('OpenSans-Italic.woff')  format('woff'),
              url('OpenSans-Italic.ttf')   format('truetype'),
              url('OpenSans-Italic.svg#svgOpenSans')  format('svg'); 
}
```

Comment: to call them on the h tags how do I do that ?

Comment: For example:
`/* Regular OpenSans */
h1{
    font-family: 'OpenSans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
/* Bold OpenSans */
h1{
    font-family: 'OpenSans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style:normal;
}
/* Italic OpenSans */
h1{
    font-family: 'OpenSans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style:italic;
}
/* Bold and Italic OpenSans */
h1{
    font-family: 'OpenSans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style:italic;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Basically for some font family you have to load separate font family for eg. for bold you have load diff. file and for italic fonts you have to load diff. file

The correct way to load web/custom fonts is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: my_bold_fonts;
    src: url(path_to_font_file_for_bold.woff);
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: my_italic_fonts;
    src: url(path_to_font_file_for_italic.woff);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

and similarly for other font weight

Now if you have use bold fonts for h1

Then you have to use

```
h1 {
  font-family: my_bold_fonts;
}
```

and for h2 (or any other element) if you need italics then use

```
h2 {
font-family: my_italic_fonts;
}
```

Comment: by what you are saying my font-family is like a class that I can call ?