# Problem with changing font-weight on imported fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I got a problem with setting up font-weight.
I tried different settings to change FuturaPT: normal, light, bold but it notching changes:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap");
@font-face {
  font-family: "FuturaPT";
  src: url("Fonts/FuturaPTLight.otf");
  src: url("Fonts/FuturaPTMedium.otf");
  src: url("Fonts/FuturaPTDemi.otf");
}

html {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
body {
  font-family: "FuturaPT", "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.text--main__1 {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  font-weight: light;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
.text--main__2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: try to add font weight 400 font weight light is 300 and your imported font is 400 and 700

Comment: Do I have to add a line:
font-weight: xxx; underneth corresponding src line?
Or I have to create a separate @font face for each font weight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple font-weights, one @font-face query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279989/multiple-font-weights-one-font-face-query)

Comment: if you want to use the uploaded font family then please follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277265/how-to-change-font-face

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change font face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277265/how-to-change-font-face)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't import Roboto if you don't need it, and then change your code in :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FuturaPT";
  src: url("Fonts/FuturaPTMedium.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "FuturaPT";
  src: url("Fonts/FuturaPTLight.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: light;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Here you can find more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279989/multiple-font-weights-one-font-face-query?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank You.
Is there any shorthand for this?

Comment: Nope, because you have to define which url is the correct one for the weight. In this case each font weight is connected to a different font. I know that all these fonts have the same font-family and only different weights but they are all from different resources and to make a right use of @font-face you have to define each one.

Answer (score 1):

Your CDN link `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap` shows that you're only asking for weights 400 and 700 (regular and bold) in the query parameter, so you don't actually import the weights you're trying to use. Just change the link to include other weights that you need, e.g. `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap`

Comment: Problem is that there is no difference beetwen 400 and 700 (normal and bald)
Another problem is that I'm focusing on "Futura PT" and secondary is "Roboto"